# HashMap to Java Object Mapping

Tags: java, hash, mapping

I have a hashmap of about 300 keys/values some of which need to go into a Java Object.

The hashmap is a mixture of strings and values from discrete fields. A sample of this hashmap is :

**Flight Hashmap:**

```
Flight: AA123
Date: 01/01/2017
Origin: LAX
PilotSurname: SMITH
PilotFirstname: Bob
PilotBirthday: 12/12/2004
PilotGender: Male (Possible values: Male/Female/Unknown)
PilotEthnicity: South American (could be Central American/North American etc)
CoPilotSurname: JONES
CoPilotFirstname: Jane
CoPilotBirthday: 11/12/2004
CoPilotGender: Female (Possible values: Male/Female/Unknown)
PilotEthnicity: Central American (could be South American/North American etc)
Stewardess1Surname: etc.....
```

This needs to go into a Java Object where neither the keys nor the values always match the attribute names. For example:

**Flight POJO**

```
ID: AA123
FlightDate: 01/01/2017
List<Crew> 
    Familyname: SMITH
    FirstName: Bob
    DOB: 01/01/2004
    Gender: Male (could be Male/Female/Transgender)
    Ethnicity: North American (possible: North or South American)

    Familyname: JONES
    FirstName: Jane
    DOB: 01/01/2004
    Gender: Female (could be Male/Female/Transgender)
    Ethnicity: North American (possible: North or South American)

    Familyname: etc...
```

How to get the Hashmap series of people into a list of people where the field names-> attributes don't match (Surname vs FamilyName, DateOfBirth vs DOB) and where some of the discrete keys don't match the valid values for the attributes (Male/Female/Unknown vs Male/Female/Transgender).

Comment: This isn't a programming question, it's a requirements question. We can't tell you what your program is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to create a function to process the HashMap and iterate over all the of keys (parsing them for keywords), and then using business logic to determine which data from the HashMap goes into your Flight object.

There is no magic "easy" button for you on this one. You need to write the Java logic yourself - preferably in a class of its own, so that if the business logic changes, you only need to modify that one class.

Good luck!

Comment: So the likes of Dozer, and MapStruct don't help?